# Python-Websockets: sends messages but cannot receive messages asynchronously

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a full duplex client that sends and receives asynchronously at the same time, using python's websockets package.

The server simply receives a message and echoes it back.

when the client sends all the messages, but doesn't receive anything at all, as if either the send is blocking the receive handler, or the handler is stuck and never updates the data.

However, the server ensures that it both received and sent the data, so I doubt that it's the problem.

I'm genuinely new to async, multithreading, and network programming in general, but this code will be reflected on an applicated that buffers audios from an incoming systems, and sends it to another service, also it can receive any messages from that service at any time regarding this session.

python 3.9.15
websockets==10.4
I've followed the tutorial on the official websockets documentation:
https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/patterns.html#consumer-and-producer

Client Code:

`

```
import asyncio

import websockets

sent = []
received = []

URL = "ws://localhost:8001"


async def update_sent(message):
    with open("sent.txt", "a+") as f:
        print(message, file=f)
    sent.append(message)
    return 0


async def update_received(message):
    with open("recv.txt", "a+") as f:
        print(message, file=f)
        received.append(message)
    return 0


async def sending_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = input("send message:>")
            await websocket.send(message)
            await update_sent(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Sender: connection closed due to Exception", e)
            break


async def receive_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            await update_received(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Receiver: connection closed due to Exception", e)
            break


async def full_duplex_handler(websocket):
    receiving_task = asyncio.create_task(receive_handler(websocket))
    sending_task = asyncio.create_task(sending_handler(websocket))

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([receiving_task, sending_task],
                                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                                       # return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
    for task in pending:
        print(task)
        task.cancel()


async def gather_handler(websocket):
    await asyncio.gather(
        sending_handler(websocket),
        receive_handler(websocket),
    )


# using asyncio.wait
async def main_1(url=URL):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        await full_duplex_handler(websocket)


# using asyncio.gather
# async def main_2(url=URL):
#     async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
#         await gather_handler(websocket)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main_1())
    # asyncio.run(main_2())
```

`

Server code:
`

```
import asyncio

import websockets

msgs = []
sent = []


async def handle_send(websocket, message):
    await websocket.send(message)
    msgs.append(message)


async def handle_recv(websocket):
    message = await websocket.recv()
    sent.append(message)
    return f"echo {message}"


async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await handle_recv(websocket)
            await handle_send(websocket, message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(msgs)
            print(sent)
            break


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8001):
        await asyncio.Future()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting the server now")
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`

After sending some messages, all sent and received messages should be written to a file,
but only sent messages are received and processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

I've put a sleep statement:

```
await asyncio.sleep(0.02)
```

in the `sending_handler` while loop, and it resolved the problem,

apparently the issue was that the sender is way faster than the receiver, that it keeps locking the resources for its use, while the receiver is being blocked.

Any shorter sleep durations can't solve this problem.

final while loop:

```
async def sending_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.02)
        try:
            message = input("send message:>")
            await websocket.send(message)
            await update_sent(message)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Sender: connection closed due to Exception", e)
            break
```

Hope this answer helps anyone else who faces the same problem