# Python synchronous pyaudio data in asynchronous code

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, pyaudio

Here is my use-case:

- I am streaming some audio from a microphone using Pyaudio. I receive chunks of audio data every x milliseconds.
- I am opening a websockets connection if some condition is met.
- Once the websockets is opened, I am streaming some messages in and out in an asyncronous manner. There is a consumer / producer way of doing things (I must be able to receive or send messages independently). The messages sent corresponds to the new chunks of data that I receive from the microphone.

The issue I have:

- the streaming from the microphone is synchronous, and is blocking the thread. I do not have a deep understanding of the event loop, but my basic understanding is that this synchronous waiting blocks everything else. The consequence is that I cannot even open the websockets connection, except if I add some asyncio.sleep everywhere, which will be not robust at all.

The way I tried to solve it:

- First idea: run the websockets connector in a second thread, and send the chunks from the main thread. The problem is that asynchronous queues are not thread safe, so in order to work I must have a synchronous queue... and the problem is still there. I also tried [this package](https://pypi.org/project/janus/) but that didn't help.
- Second idea: running everything in an asynchronous fashion. But the synchronous incoming data is blocking everything.
- Third idea: implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993334/converting-a-python-function-with-a-callback-to-an-asyncio-awaitable) in the following manner (code below). The idea is to use Pyaudio callbacks with an asynchronous stream.

```
import asyncio
import msgpack
import os
import websockets
import asyncio
import pyaudio
from src.utils.constants import CHANNELS, CHUNK, FORMAT, RATE
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from .utils import websocket_data_packet  # just a utils function

load_dotenv()

QUEUE_MAX_SIZE = 10
MY_URL = os.environ.get("WEBSOCKETS_URL")

def make_iter():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    def put(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue
    async def get():
        while True:
            yield await queue.get()
    return get(), put


class MicrophoneStreamer(object):
    chunk: int = CHUNK
    channels: int = CHANNELS
    format: int = FORMAT
    rate: int = RATE

    def __init__(self):
        self._pyaudio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.is_stream_open: bool = True
        self.stream_get, stream_put = make_iter()
        self.stream = self._pyaudio.open(
            format=self.format,
            channels=self.channels,
            rate=self.rate,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self.chunk,
            stream_callback=stream_put,
        )
        self.stream.start_stream()
        
    def close(self):
        self.is_stream_open = False
        self.stream.close()
        self._pyaudio.terminate()


async def consumer(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(f"Received message: {msgpack.unpackb(message)}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


async def producer(websocket, audio_queue):
    while True:
        chunck = await audio_queue.get()
        print(f"Sending message with audio data of size: {len(chunck)}")
        await websocket.send(msgpack.packb(websocket_data_packet(chunck)))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


async def handler(audio_queue):
    print("This is before creating a new websocket")
    async with websockets.connect(MY_URL) as websocket:
        print("Just created a new websocket")
        producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(websocket, audio_queue))
        consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(websocket))
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [consumer_task, producer_task],
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
            timeout=60,
        )
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()
        websocket.close()


async def main():
    audio_queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=5)
    i = 0

    async for in_data in MicrophoneStreamer().stream_get:
        print(f"Processing item {len(in_data)}")
        # on trigger, create websockets connection
        if i == 2:
            asyncio.create_task(handler(audio_queue))
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # starts the task
        # on each iteration, add element to the queue
        if audio_queue.full():
            _ = await audio_queue.get()
        await audio_queue.put(in_data)
        i += 1


asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run this code, here is what happens:

- before i==2, elements gets added to the queue, everything works fine.
- then, at i==2, the websockets get opened, messages get out and get in without issue
- but then, the loop blocks. No new incoming bytes from the microphone streamer. Nothing happens anymore.

Would somebody know how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes - open the blocking thing in a second thread, and use a "plain" `queue.Queue()` to pass data back and forth. On the asynchronous end, all you have to do is not to try a blocking read of the queue - there are `get_nowait`  and timeout=0  approaches to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great idea, I just tried and this almost works. The consumer and producer queue are then kind of "racing" (if one of them runs too fast, the other cant run), and I have to add an ugly asyncio.sleep(0.02) as pointed out in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994040/12176803). I had a similar version working before, but thought that going to an asynchronous queue would allow to solve this issue, as awaiting a new result would leave place for the other task to run. Or maybe using this asyncio.sleep is not the way to go? I can post the code if needed. Thank you!

Comment: that will vary. Adding `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in async code is something that is oddly needed when writting Python asyncio code. (0.02 will also work, but needing the ".02" or other arbitrary value is less common) - the "0" wait in sleep is handled in a separate code path, and just yields the control to the asyncio loop. If there are no awaits in a loop in an async function, the loop will never be reached, and other tasks will stall.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(0)` does not work for me, the .02 seems necessary in this case. It is true that it is quite odd and not very good, but I guess I'll live with it then. Thank you for your time and answer.